# PSQL function help - date format issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Just trying to clean up some functions someone else has done in a postgres.

Would anyone know what the following does? It was working, but the date format changed when it started coming in as '1999-09-07 16:30:00.000'

I don't know what the previous format was.

```
select 
case 
    when dbDate = '' then null
    when dbDate != '^\d.*' then dbDate::timestamp
    else '1900-01-01'::date + dbDate::int   
end as dbDate
```

Whenever I call the function with the date it gives me

`invalid input syntax for integer: "1999-09-07 16:30:00.000"`

Comment: Why are you casting `dbDate` as an integer?

Comment: I didn't write the code, so I am not sure. should that be dbDate::timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

This nice function was taking multiple kinds of date inputs and normalizing them.

I assume it expected one of:

- blank which it let be null
- a date starting with 'MMM' in date format which would not pass '^\d.*' (i.e. something that doesn’t start with a number) which it would cast as a date
- a number

The reason that the date was being casted as an `INT` is because after failing the first two tests the person writing this was *expecting* an `INT`.  They wanted to add the integer to the beginning of Time (i.e. 1900-01-01) like Excel does.

`1999-09-07 16:30:00.000` fails the second test even though it could be cast as time.

This passes through to the `else`, which fails to cast it as `INT`, and throws the error.

In this case, you need to change your second test.  Make it something that will allow a datetime that you have coming in, but that would reject a number that should be added to `1900-01-01`.

If you don’t think you will have numbers coming in that should be added to `1900-01-01`, then just get rid of the third test and use

```
select 
case 
    when dbDate = '' then null
    else dbDate::timestamp
end as dbDate
```

Comment: would the replace command be:

    replace dateconverter select case  when dbDate = '' then null else   dbDate::timestamp end as dbDate

Comment: Honestly I think it depends on what the previous format was and what kind of data you typically get on dbdate field.  Run a query to pull all unique dbdates and check it out.  If you see a lot of integers that make sense when added to the old date format you may need to make some changes to the function to allow for this data.  If they are all datetime or zls you could use the above.

Comment: Did this solution work for you?  If you are selecting INTs rather than Dates and getting some strange Datetimes, we can work on a way to accept the incoming INTs and change them to dates as the Function initially did.